# Quantifier matrix

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $A$ be a matrix with $m$ rows and $n$ columns. $a_{ij}$ denotes the real number in the cell in row $i$ and column $j$.
How can I express (with a quantified statement) that:

- All diagonal elements of $A$ are equal to $0$.
- The largest value in the first row of $A$ is equal to $7$.

My answers:

- $\forall i \forall j [i =j \to a_{ij}=0]$
- $\exists j[a_{1j}=7] \land\forall j[a_{1j} \leq7]$

I would like to know if my answers are correct.

Comment: Personally, I would add parenthesis to avoid parsing errors on the part of people; but I have been traumatized by "bad" parsers.   In my experience, for elementary classes I would ditch the "->" in favour of and's/or's/not's.  Of course in the "real" world "->" is fine.